# Converting one normal distribution to another

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a long data similar to this; between 15 and 25

consider its mean as m and calculated standard deviation using this formula.

[image]

I assumed the above data as a normally distributed data and can calculate Zscore using this formula

[image]

I want to convert the X data to an another normal distribution data  Y

```
X                  Y
15              50
15.1578368505   49.928991715
15.4012367562   49.5834109487
15.519892273    49.4143896331
15.6799092721   49.2835022539
15.9227554377   49.2641596452
21.1484143527   3.5582245984
21.3897462389   3.3444121792
21.5833838186   3.3247349532
25              1
```

here also i have one more condition

From the X series lowest value(ie 15) will point to the highest Y(ie 50) and the highest X series value(25) will point to the lowest of Y series(1)
value

eg: if i select `X=16 then Y=48.33`

What should i do know?

Edited
I have tried this

- Calculated Z score of X series
- Used this Z score to find **x** in the second equation
- The resultant **x** gave approximate results

  ```
     15=0.8567432(approximately to 1)
     25=50.367857(approximately to 50)
  ```

But I wanted like this

```
       15=50.367857(approximately to 50)
       25=0.8567432(approximately to 1)
```

any idea?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  If X is normally distributed by, e.g., ($\mu, \sigma$) then -X is normally distributed by ($-\mu, \sigma$)  and that has the effect of "flipping the order", so the smallest of your data is now the greatest and so on.  You can then shift the mean and st. dev. as in your Z formula.  Is this what you were after?

Comment: @lulu have edited the question for clarity.